# How to animate the Foreground property of multiple "Run" elements in a TextBlock in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have this code. This is just an example. I want to do it with code. How to animate the Foreground property of multiple "Run" elements in a TextBlock?

```
<Page
    x:Class="AnimationTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:AnimationTest"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>

        <TextBlock
            x:Name="_textBlockElement"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="72"><Run x:Name="_run1" Text="Hel" /><Run Text="lo" />
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="ColorStoryboard">
                            <ColorAnimation
                                AutoReverse="True"
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="_textBlockElement"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="Red"
                                Duration="0:0:2" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: During the testing, `<Run x:Name="_run1" Text="Hel" /><Run Text="lo" />` could be add the animation at same time. Could you tell what feature you want to implement ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, there is a TextBlock, which consists of several "Run" elements. Each element is painted in its own color. I need to make all the Run elements turn red when the mouse is over the TextBlock. When the mouse cursor moves away from the TextBlock, all Run elements have returned to their previous colors. I will do this from the code. The XAML code is just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oke, so this took quite some sorting out, but turned out to be quite doable.

The key is to create two storyboards in code behind with the correct animations and then add those storyboards to the resources of any parent of the `Run`'s.

Let's start of with the `XAML` code, which is pretty simple:

```xml
<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TestBlock"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
               PointerEntered="TestBlock_PointerEntered"
               PointerExited="TestBlock_PointerExited">
        <Run x:Name="Run1" Text="Test1" Foreground="Blue"/>
        <Run x:Name="Run2" Text="Test2" Foreground="Green"/>
        <!-- ... -->
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

For simplicity I have already defined the names and foregrounds of the `Run`'s.

**Now we need to define the storyboards and animations in code behind.**
I've chosen to do this in the constructor (**after `InitializeComponent()`**!). In theory you should be able to also paste this code in the `Page_Loaded` event.

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetupStoryBoards();
}

void SetupStoryBoards()
{
    // Define duration and storyboards to red and original color
    var duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    var toRedStory = new Storyboard { Duration = duration };
    // completed events can be subscribed to, to register when animation is done
    //toRedStory.Completed += Story_Completed;

    var toOriginalStory = new Storyboard { Duration = duration };
    //toOriginalStory.Completed += ToOriginalStory_Completed;

    foreach (Run r in TestBlock.Inlines)
    {
        // Filter out any inlines that are not a named Run
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Name))
            continue;

        // Define the animations
        var toRedAnim = new ColorAnimation
        {
            Duration = duration,
            To = Colors.Red,
            EnableDependentAnimation = true
        };
        var toOriginalAnim = new ColorAnimation
        {
            Duration = duration,
            To = (r.Foreground as SolidColorBrush).Color, // Causes animation to go back to original foreground color of Run
            EnableDependentAnimation = true
        };

        // Add animations to the storyboards and associate animations with the Run
        toRedStory.Children.Add(toRedAnim);
        toOriginalStory.Children.Add(toOriginalAnim);

        Storyboard.SetTargetName(toRedAnim, r.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(toOriginalAnim, r.Name);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(toRedAnim, "(Run.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)");
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(toOriginalAnim, "(Run.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)");
    }

    // Add the storyboards to the resources of any parent of the Run's for easy retrieval later and to make the animations find the Run's
    // I choose the resources of the textblock that contains the Run's
    TestBlock.Resources.Add("toRedStory", toRedStory);
    TestBlock.Resources.Add("toOriginalStory", toOriginalStory);
}
```

Now to execute the animations, we add the `PointerEntered` and `PointerExited` eventhandlers, and begin the correct storyboards there:

```cs
private void TextBlock_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var story = TestBlock.Resources["toRedStory"] as Storyboard;
    story.Begin();
}

private void TextBlock_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var story = TestBlock.Resources["toOriginalStory"] as Storyboard;
    story.Begin();
}
```

> You should be able to extend this wherever needed, however I have found that `EnableDependentAnimation` must be set to `true` since otherwise it won't work.